# Editing changing Facebook settings in Unity inspector gives OpenSSL error that won't fix

Tags: facebook, variables, unity-game-engine, openssl

I am getting this error:

```
Win32Exception: ApplicationName='cmd', CommandLine='/Cecho "xxx" | openssl base64', CurrentDirectory=''
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_noshell (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process process)
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_common (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process process)
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start ()
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process:Start ()
UnityEditor.FacebookEditor.FacebookAndroidUtil.DoesCommandExist (System.String command) (at Assets/Facebook/Editor/android/FacebookAndroidUtil.cs:164)
UnityEditor.FacebookEditor.FacebookAndroidUtil.get_DebugKeyHash () (at Assets/Facebook/Editor/android/FacebookAndroidUtil.cs:66)
UnityEditor.FacebookEditor.FacebookAndroidUtil.get_SetupProperly () (at Assets/Facebook/Editor/android/FacebookAndroidUtil.cs:44)
Facebook.Unity.Editor.FacebookSettingsEditor.AndroidUtilGUI () (at Assets/Facebook/Editor/FacebookSettingsEditor.cs:178)
Facebook.Unity.Editor.FacebookSettingsEditor.OnInspectorGUI () (at Assets/Facebook/Editor/FacebookSettingsEditor.cs:63)
UnityEditor.InspectorWindow.DrawEditor (UnityEditor.Editor editor, Int32 editorIndex, Boolean rebuildOptimizedGUIBlock, System.Boolean& showImportedObjectBarNext, UnityEngine.Rect& importedObjectBarRect) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Inspector/InspectorWindow.cs:1235)
UnityEditor.DockArea:OnGUI()
```

Here is my path environment variable:

[image]

This is my JDK/bin folder:

[image]

I'd show you the OpenSSL folder but I can't post more than two pictures..
The OpenSSL folder is located t C:\OpenSSL\bin

I've been stuck on this error for days now, please help me.